# Newline characters generated in Python script not accepted in another job

Tags: python, linux, newline

I have a certain combination of application in which a certain part of it accepts a bunch of parameters from a file. All the stuff I am using is Linux-based.

The problem is, something in my work-pipe does not like the newline character. On one side, I write a script like this:

```
with open(job_script_file, 'w') as f:
     f.write("parameter 1 goes here\n")
     f.write("parameter 2 goes here\n")
     f.write("python script call plus arguments here")
```

However these arguments are rejected by the job manager UNLESS I manually edit the job script before running. If I manually scramble the newlines, doing some modifications, it works. If I do no manual editing at all (straight from the python script) it doesn't work.

Are there any suggestions as to why this newline character (or maybe it's something else entirely) is not being accepted/read correctly by the csh job script?

---

One thing I tried was using sed -i to edit the file in place and add an empty line before the python call:

```
sed -i 's/^python/\n\python/g'
```

While this edited the file, the problem persisted.

UPDATE: As requested in the comments, a head/tail hexdump of a file that worked (after manually editing the file):

```
od -xc <working_file> | head -15
0000000    2123    622f    6e69    632f    6873    2d20    0a66    5323
          #   !   /   b   i   n   /   c   s   h       -   f  \n   #   S
0000020    4142    4354    2048    2d2d    6f6a    2d62    616e    656d
          B   A   T   C   H       -   -   j   o   b   -   n   a   m   e
0000040    573d    3056    5f31    3032    3431    3730    3931    315f
          =   W   V   0   1   _   2   0   1   4   0   7   1   9   _   1
0000060    3230    3030    3031    3230    3946    3344    3045    5f30
          0   2   0   0   1   0   0   2   F   9   D   3   E   0   0   _
0000100    3031    3032    3130    3030    3133    3634    3130    3030
          1   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   3   1   4   6   0   1   0   0
0000120    322d    3130    3037    3033    2d36    6574    7473    6a5f
          -   2   0   1   7   0   3   0   6   -   t   e   s   t   _   j
0000140    626f    230a    4253    5441    4843    2d20    6e2d    646f
          o   b  \n   #   S   B   A   T   C   H       -   -   n   o   d
0000160    7365    313d    230a    4253    5441    4843    2d20    632d

od -xc <working_file> | tail -10
          i   n   :   :   1   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   3   1   4   6
0007140    3130    3030    3520    3030    3733    3238    3432    3231
          0   1   0   0       5   0   0   3   7   8   2   2   4   1   2
0007160    3a30    6a3a    696f    3a6e    353a    3030    3733    3339
          0   :   :   j   o   i   n   :   :   5   0   0   3   7   9   3
0007200    3337    3131    2030    3222    3130    2d34    3730    312d
          7   3   1   1   0       "   2   0   1   4   -   0   7   -   1
0007220    2239    000a
          9   "  \n
0007223
```

and the same for a non-working file:

```
od -xc <non-working_file> | head -15
0000000    2123    622f    6e69    632f    6873    2d20    0a66    5323
          #   !   /   b   i   n   /   c   s   h       -   f  \n   #   S
0000020    4142    4354    2048    2d2d    6f6a    2d62    616e    656d
          B   A   T   C   H       -   -   j   o   b   -   n   a   m   e
0000040    573d    3056    5f31    3032    3431    3630    3731    315f
          =   W   V   0   1   _   2   0   1   4   0   6   1   7   _   1
0000060    3230    3030    3031    3230    3844    4644    3035    5f30
          0   2   0   0   1   0   0   2   D   8   D   F   5   0   0   _
0000100    3031    3032    3130    3030    3233    3241    3132    3030
          1   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   3   2   A   2   2   1   0   0
0000120    322d    3130    3037    3033    2d36    6574    7473    6a5f
          -   2   0   1   7   0   3   0   6   -   t   e   s   t   _   j
0000140    626f    230a    4253    5441    4843    2d20    6e2d    646f
          o   b  \n   #   S   B   A   T   C   H       -   -   n   o   d
0000160    7365    313d    230a    4253    5441    4843    2d20    632d


od -xc <non-working_file> | tail -10
          n   :   :   1   0   2   0   0   1   0   0   3   2   A   2   2
0007140    3031    2030    3035    3330    3536    3037    3136    3038
          1   0   0       5   0   0   3   6   5   7   0   6   1   8   0
0007160    3a3a    6f6a    6e69    3a3a    3035    3330    3837    3833
          :   :   j   o   i   n   :   :   5   0   0   3   7   8   3   8
0007200    3134    3035    2220    3032    3431    302d    2d36    3731
          4   1   5   0       "   2   0   1   4   -   0   6   -   1   7
0007220    0022
          "
0007221
```

Comment: Did you tried using `os.linesep`? So you can use `f.write("data" + os.linesep)`

Comment: If the job manager program has any sort of Windows heritage, perhaps it's looking for the Windows line ending (``"\r\n"``), not just a newline?

Comment: @jasonharper I should have mentioned that I did "\r\n" too and got an error. Thanks though

Comment: If it works when you edit the file manually, and it does not work when you create it from Python, there should be a difference. Could you show here a hexadecimal dump of a working and of a non working file (`od -xc file | head -15` should be enough)

Comment: And the end of file can be interesting too, so unless the dump of the beginning makes the problem evident, could you also dump the end of a working and of a non working file (`od -xc file | tail -10`) - some editors add a Ctrl-Z character at the end of file...

Comment: There is too much text in this question, IMHO. Could you provide hexdump for both a working file and also for a non-working file? That way we may have some light into the real problem. Also: please include the `\r\n` being already tested into the question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - thank you both. Please see the update which includes the hexdump for both an edited working and non-edited, non-working file.

Comment: @MariusSiuram - done. thank you. please see my updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edits the problem is now clear: the *non working file* simply lacks a newline after the command (the last `\n` in the *working file*). The fix is now easy, just add it on last write:

```
with open(job_script_file, 'w') as f:
     f.write("parameter 1 goes here\n")
     f.write("parameter 2 goes here\n")
     f.write("python script call plus arguments here\n")  # \n to cleanly end the command
```

As there was no new line on the last line, the job manager saw it as uncompleted and could not process it. And most editor consistently force a new line at the end of a text file, which explains why any edition on the file resulted in a *working file*.

Comment: Thanks Serge. I will try this to confirm when I get the chance. A couple of questions...1) Any idea why this newline character at the end of the python call affects the script working? And 2) Why does my editing the file manually, even though I wasn't adding/editing anything to the end of the file/python call but just before the call, add a newline to the end? Thanks so much

Comment: That seemed to work but I still need to test it all the way through. Is it better to write the script with a newline on the first server like you suggested or use sed -i to add the newline to the end of file on the second server: "sed -i '$a\' <file>" ? Thank you

Comment: @user20408: I've edited the post to better explain why any edition made the file work. For you last question, IMHO you should always write a new line at the end of a text file, because it is the common usage of most text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer may help you:

```
from os import linesep

with open("your_script_file", 'w') as f:
    f.write("your_data" + linesep)
    f.write("your_data_too" + linesep)
```

For more information click on this link: [os.linesep](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.linesep)

**Caution:**

> Do not use os.linesep as a line terminator when writing files opened
>   in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all
>   platforms.

Comment: Will try this when I get in. Thank you!

Comment: If I recall correctly, given that the file is opened without the `b` (binary) mode, the "\n" is translated into an OS-native carriage return. But maybe I am confusing with C++ standard library or some other language. I don't have a windows machine near to test it.

Comment: Yes @MariusSiuram. You're right. I din't pay attention to this line in python documentation: Do not use os.linesep as a line terminator when writing files opened in text mode (the default); use a single '\n' instead, on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If native Python solutions don't work, first you should try this:

```
with open(job_script_file, 'w') as f:
     f.write("parameter 1 goes here@")
     f.write("parameter 2 goes here@")
     f.write("python script call plus arguments here")
```

And then:

```
tr '@' '\n' < file.txt
```

If you can take for granted that the character @ won't be present on the parameters. Also try \r instead of \n and see what happens.

Otherwise, as a last resort you can use [xdotool](http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse) to automatically do the manual changes for you. ( [documentation](http://semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) )